# Changed mouse event handling from Java 1.5 to 1.6

Tags: java, events, mouse

We recently moved one of our (edit) Linux java applications from java 1.5 to java 1.6 and got bitten quite hard by what seems to be a change in MouseEvent sending between the two versions, which left our application very unhappy for a few days until we tracked it down.

In short, when the user right clicks on a class ultimately derived from awt.Canvas to bring up a JPopupMenu, in Java 1.5 the originating canvas receives the right mouse up event, but in Java 1.6 we never hear the mouse up event. This sends our application into a tizzy, as it's maintaining an internal mouse button map, and gets into an inconsistent state.

(edit) This *only* applies to Linux - on Windows we receive mouse up event on both java 1.5 and 1.6.

I've written a short program which creates a canvas and attaches a popup menu to it, triggered by right mouse click, and logs the events to the console. If I compile and run this under java 1.5 and do a left click then a right click, I see the following:

EventCanvas->mousePressed  mb: [L..]
EventCanvas->Released      mb: [...]
EventCanvas->mouseClicked  mb: [...]
EventCanvas->mousePressed  mb: [..R]
EventCanvas->Released      mb: [...]

but if I do the same under java 1.6 I see:

EventCanvas->mousePressed  mb: [L..]
EventCanvas->Released      mb: [...]
EventCanvas->mouseClicked  mb: [...]
EventCanvas->mousePressed  mb: [..R]

My question, such as it is: Is this well known? Well documented? Are there standard workarounds for this sort of situation?

We have a happily operational program again now, so this question is just out of curiosity - but I was surprised to see a change like this between versions. BTW - if someone wants to tell me it's a bit odd to be keeping an internal map of mouse state, perhaps so, but we're talking a large gui intensive legacy application here, and a large scale rewrite isn't always an option.

The sample code can be seen at: http://teapot7.com/sample.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you're experiencing.  I compiled your code with java 1.6 and for every mouse click (left or right) I get three events:  Pressed, Released, Clicked.  Every time.  I may not be understanding what you're seeing.

Comment: Aargh! I stupidly forgot to say this happens on Linux and not on Windows, which continues to behave the same as java 1.5 My apologies. Were you testing on Windows?

Comment: yes I was testing on Windows :)

Answer (score 1):

> My question, such as it is: Is this well known?   Well documented?

It is not entirely clear what your problem is (see @RD's comment), so I cannot say for this one.

In general, changes that are known to impact on applications are documented in the respective "JDK Adoption Guide" documents.  In the JDK 6 document, the [AWT section](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/adoptionguide-137484.html#2.1.4) lists various fixes that have changed the events that applications may see.  (Under the heading "Changes in event firing".)  One of them looks like it might describe what you are seeing.

Other places where changes like this might be documented are in the Release Notes (which list all fixed bugs in each minor release) and the Bug Database.

Whether this counts as "well documented" is for you to judge.  But I reckon it does.

> Are there standard workarounds for this sort of situation?

In general, no ... apart from rolling back to the older JVM until you can find a fix.

What would a "standard workaround" for "something has changed in Swing / AWT" be?

Comment: What would a standard workaround be? Well, at one point we were considering creating the missing mouse event ourselves. I'm very glad we didn't have to go there in the end :)

Comment: Well, they say: "Multiple problems in event firing were fixed: fallacious and duplicate events removed..." which certainly fits the bill, but none of the bug numbers they quote exactly match my problem - and the fact that the behavior is different between Linux and Windows makes me suspicious.

Comment: Well perhaps it is a new JDK 6 bug on Linux.  Have you tried testing with different JDK 6 patch releases?